# how much difference is permissible in focal length of cameras in stereo camera?

Tags: opencv, triangulation, 3d-reconstruction

I have performed single camera calibration using openCV library before performing stereo calibration and,
results of single camera calibration are:

focal length of camera 1 is: fx=1.2462718254982949e+003, fy=1.2462718254982949e+003 ,  with avg reprojection error=3.3547184378077333e-001

focal length of camera 2 is:fx= 1.6148973771889357e+003,
fy=1.6148973771889357e+003 with avg reprojection error=3.4419465826561280e-001

Is this difference is permissible for a stereo camera and
With these focal lengths can i get a good depth estimation after stereo calibration and rectification?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about optics, not programming.

Comment: its about image processing using opencv library in C++,  then how can u say its not programming  @MSalters

Comment: The question is also written in English, still doesn't make it on-topic for English.SE either. "Focal lengths" simply are a concept in optics, not in C++.

Comment: i have tagged the question in opencv and 3d reconstruction category not in C++ and those who have knowledge about the topic can understand my question.